# Do Scavenger Trinkets stack in co-op Orcs Must Die 2?

Tags: orcs-must-die-2

In Orcs Must Die 2, the Scavenger Trinket gives all enemies a chance to drop coins; unlike the other trinkets which are only for the character using them (barring a few activated abilities) it applies for both characters in co-op play (since it doesn't really affect *players*).

The question is, in co-op play if *both* characters bring the Scavenger Trinket do you get double the chance of bonus coins, or is the 2nd Scavenger Trinket a waste?

EDIT: This is specifically about the **passive** boost from the Trinket. Testing with a buddy has determined how the active ability of the Trinket functions, see answer below.

Comment: Are you *sure* it affects both players?  If only one has the trinket, will kills by either player drop a coin?

Comment: The coin drops aren't assigned to a specific character; the Rift Guardian Trinket ups lives, and it definitely stacks when both players bring it.

Comment: Not 100%, but when I'm using the Scavenger trinket, I seem to get a lot more coins generated around my kills than my co-op partner; could be a ranged effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to a Robot Entertainment employee:

> A little trinket design heads up.
>
> Trinket passives apply to the owning player only while the active effect apply to both the owning and the coop player.
>
> Example: The healing trinket only passively grants regeneration to the player that equips it but activating it will heal himself and their coop partner.

I did find a specific mention of the scavenger trinket having a unique property:

> All Trinket Passives apply provided they are in your loadout, and only for you not your co-op partner. The only exception is Scavenger, So long as one of your traps added a combo point scavenger applies its passive effect even if the killing blow was dealt by your co-op partner.
>
> All Trinket Active effects apply to both players.

**Source**: [Robot Entertainment Forums](http://www.robotentertainment.com/forum/topic/Trinket-Info#comment-81472)

**Source**: [Scavenger Trinket Passive](http://www.robotentertainment.com/forum/topic/Trinket-passive-question#comment-84820)

Comment: Yeah, I had heard that they said that, but I'm not convinced it's actually true. A friend and I tested the Trap Reset Trinket, for example, and found the exact opposite to be true: the passive applied to both characters' traps (and didn't stack), while the active only affected the traps of the character that brought the trinket.

Comment: I tested the health regeneration trinket and it worked like the developer suggested. It might be worth testing all of the trinkets, but I need to earn some more skulls for that.

Comment: You can reset your skulls any time you're in the campaign menu, which makes testing stuff easy **if** you can figure out a good way to test it. I asked this question because my friend and I couldn't figure out a good way to determine whether the Scavenger Trinket passive is shared between players, and if so whether it stacks.

Comment: True, I didn't think about the skull reset feature. I have a couple of ideas on how to test it. Probably go through level one with a friend and note how many coins drop. Then do it with us both having the trinket. It isn't a perfect test, but it should give an idea of how it works after a few runs.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I did find a mention of the scavenger trinket on the official forums. The sharing the effect if any damage is done, might explain why testing it got some odd results.

Answer (score 2):

The **active** ability of the Scavenger Trinket *mostly* stacks in co-op play. If only one player has the active ability activated, both players benefit from it. If both players have the Trinket activated at the same time, however, only the *host* gains the benefits of *both* Trinkets (the other player continues gaining only the benefits of a single Trinket activation).