# How does the active ability of the scavenger trinket work?

Tags: orcs-must-die-2

It happens quite often that I cannot activate the Scavenger Trinket after having used and it has cooled down. I have no idea why as the icon shows it to be completely cooled down but when I select it and click like mad, nothing happens for a long time. If I switch to my weapon, kill some orks and wait some time it will work again.

Answer (score 1):

While the scavenger trinket is active, your character will have a blue-glow, and get an extra 1 gold every time you (or one of your traps) kill a unit.

The amount you earn for a kill is always shown breifly as a number displayed over the orc when you kill it; this number will go up by 1 when the scavenger trinket is active.

See also [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79138) for information on how the ability stacks in coop.

---

The issues you are having are probably due to the trinket being on cooldown *(shown in your inventory as being partially grayed-out)*, or not having enough mana to cast it *(the blue bar at the upper-left of your screen)*.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the active ability of the trinket ups kill value by 50%.  In co-op, the heavy orcs were worth 10 gold, but with the trinket active, they were worth 15.

Comment: Voted up for mana requirement. Scavenger trinkets requires a lot of mana to activate.